# can't access member even after making a member function a friend

Tags: c++

In the code below if, I make the `College` class friend of `University` class then I am able to access the private attributes of `University` class. But in `College` class I only want the print function to access those private attributes. So, I only made `print` function of `College` class as friend but that doesn't seem to work. What's is it that I am missing or doing wrong?

Error: Can't access name private attribute of `University` class.

```
#include <iostream>

//class college; 

class University{
    //friend class college;   // Works fine
    friend void College::print(University &ob);    // doesn't work

public:
    University() = default;

    University(int i, char *n) : buildings{ i }, name{ n } {}

private:
    int buildings; 
    char *name; 
};

class College{
public:
    void print(University &ob){
        std::cout << "I am a part of " << ob.name;   // <-----------
    }
};

int main()
{
    University first{ 2000, "Mit" };

    College c; 
    c.print(first); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `College` is not declared yet. Instead, make an initial forward declaration of University, then define College with just the member function declarations. Then define University, then define Colleges member functions.

Comment: @Columbo even after forward declaration of College class i see that error....see i have commented out that line

Comment: @androidplusios.design You misunderstood what I wrote.

Comment: @androidplusios.design a forward declaration isn't sufficient. An example of what Columbo was talking about can be found in RSahu's answer. Personally I'd use a public getter and call it good. Btw, those `char*` should be `const char*`

Comment: @Columbo  ohh i get it know

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to use

```
friend void College::print(University &ob);
```

The definition of the class `College` must be visible.

```
class University;

class College{
public:
    void print(University &ob);
};

class University{
    //friend class college;   // Works fine
    friend void College::print(University &ob);

public:
    University() = default;

    University(int i, char *n) : buildings{ i }, name{ n } {}

private:
    int buildings; 
    char *name; 
};

void Collelge::print(University &ob){
        std::cout << "I am a part of " << ob.name;   // <-----------
}
```

Comment: @R Sahu what is the reason behind that ? From the revised code that you have written, what i understood is that the compiler doesn't know the class College has a print() function inside of it....So we need to declare the function we are using along with class declaration. Have i got it right or its some other  reason ?